# Is it safe to extend an Objective-C class in Swift with non-prefixed methods?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c-category, swift-extensions

In Objective-C, one should always prefix category methods, e.g. if extending `UIView` with the method `descendants`, you'd add `zzz_` and make it `zzz_descendants` to avoid naming conflicts. Is that necessary for a function in `extension UIView { ... }` in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary in order to compile. However, it's a good idea to prefix extension methods to avoid possible conflicts later on, in case Apple should introduce a method by the same name. An even more important reason, in my opinion, is to make clear that the extension method is custom code and not part of the standard API.